# Page Div align not showing correctly

Tags: asp.net, html, markup

I have a weird situation and believe that it must be easy for people to help me out on this specific issue. I have two divs on a child page that i want to show next to each other. I mean, One on left and one on right. After that, on the bottom of the screen I want to display a table that covers 100% width.

I have used float left on one div and float right on another div. Then i show the heading of the table on the bottom, then the table displays.
My problem is that the despite all my efforts the heading is displaying in between these two divs. Here is my code.

```
   <div id="ContainerDiv" runat="server" style="width: 930px">
        <div id="DivticketDetails" runat="server" visible="false" 
            style="float: left; width: 400px;">
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelTicketDetails" runat="server" BackColor="#8B9FBE">
                <h3 style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">
                    Bowzer Details</h3>
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="myTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#507CD1">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Field / Customer Name" Font-Bold="True"
                                Font-Size="XX-Small" BorderColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_FieldName" runat="server" Text="lbl_FieldName" CssClass="myLabel"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#507CD1">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Challan Generated On" Font-Bold="True"
                                Font-Size="XX-Small" BorderColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_firstEntryDate" runat="server" Text="lbl_firstEntryDate" Font-Size="Small"
                                CssClass="myLabel"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#507CD1">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Product Name" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Small"
                                BorderColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_ProductName" runat="server" Text="lbl_ProductName" Font-Size="Small"
                                CssClass="myLabel"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#507CD1">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Bowzer No" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Small"
                                BorderColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_bowzerNo" runat="server" Text="lbl_bowzerNo" Font-Size="Small"
                                CssClass="myLabel"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#507CD1">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Text="Quantity" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Small"
                                BorderColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_BowQuantity" runat="server" Text="lbl_BowQuantity" Font-Size="Small"
                                CssClass="myLabel"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
        <div id="Div2" runat="server" style="float: right; width: 429px;">
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelBowzerHistory" runat="server" BackColor="#8B9FBE" Visible="False">
                <h3 style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; color: #FFFFFF">
                    Bowzer History
                </h3>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    DataKeyNames="challan_id" DataSourceID="DSBowzerHistory" Font-Size="Smaller"
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstWeight" HeaderText="FirstWeight" SortExpression="FirstWeight" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstentry_date" HeaderText="Firstentry_date" SortExpression="Firstentry_date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SecondWeight" HeaderText="SecondWeight" SortExpression="SecondWeight" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="netWeight" HeaderText="netWeight" SortExpression="netWeight" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SecondEntry_Date" HeaderText="SecondEntry_Date" SortExpression="SecondEntry_Date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="challan_id" HeaderText="challan_id" InsertVisible="False"
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="challan_id" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tblDetailsDiv" runat="server" visible="False" title="Ticket Details" style="width: 930px;
        background-color: #8B9FBE;">
                <h3 style="font-size: medium; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; width: 930px; background-color: #00FF00;">
                Enter Details Here</h3>
            <table id="tblDetails" title="Enter Details" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                class="myTable" frame="border">
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
</table>
</div>
```

and here is how it is displayed.

[image]

Comment: not using any css.. just a normal formatting that already appears in the markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the float of second div to left, and after those two div.
Like this:

[image]

And add a new div with a clear style after those two divs.

[image: <div style=”clear: both”></div>]
Hope it works.

here u go. i added the code above

Comment: having a div with clear style on both side did the trick... thanks a lot.. I have another question that i'll post in a bit... plz respond to that too